# Select all 'tr' except the first one

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select all `tr` elements except the first `tr` in a table with CSS?

I tried using [this](http://www.daniel-lemire.com/blog/archives/2008/08/22/how-to-select-even-or-odd-rows-in-a-table-using-css-3/) method, but found that it did not work.

Comment: What browsers does this need to be compatible to?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: @Pekka's question is important, because I can't think of any way to do this using standard CSS that will work with various versions of IE. If you need to support IE, the only workable solution is a class for the first `<tr>` and a different class for the rest of them.

Comment: i am not worried about IE but it will work in FF and GC

Answer (score 546, accepted):

By adding a class to either the first `tr` or the subsequent `tr`s. There is no crossbrowser way of selecting the rows you want with CSS alone.

However, if you don't care about Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8:

```
tr:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I would also like to point out `tr:not(:first-of-type)` as a potential solution as well, if you're looking for the first instance of a specific selector rather than the first generalized child.

Comment: I think in 2019 we are done with IE (less than 0.5% of users of IE6 to IE10

Comment: `css_selector_here:nth-child(n + 2) { /* properties */}` Selects every DOM element of the selector that is not the first child of its parent.  In other words, every child element of the parent except the first one.  So, this will affect the child nodes in multiple parent nodes, not just one.

Answer (score 239):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the use of sibling combinators, which are supported by IE7 and later:

```
tr + tr /* CSS2, adjacent sibling */
tr ~ tr /* CSS3, general sibling */
```

They both function in exactly the same way (in the context of HTML tables anyway) as:

```
tr:not(:first-child)
```

Comment: Wait...how should this be the accepted answer?  You can't get "all but first" from that statement, which is what OP is asking.  tr+tr will get you a single element.  I guess tr~tr will get you all (I guess something like parent:first-child~tr), but not in syntactically as readable a way as not:

Comment: @hairbo: tr+tr will get you any tr that directly follows another tr. If you have a table with three rows, the third row directly follows the second row, so it will also match. You will only get a single element if you use tr:first-child+tr instead. The only difference between + and ~ is that ~ permits any number of other elements in between the two mentioned.

Comment: Just wanted to add, `elem + elem` is a great general solution for when the elements you want to target are not the only children. For example, if a `<h2>` is followed by several `<p>` tags, the first `<p>` is not the first-child in that case.

Answer (score 30):

ideal solution but not supported in IE

```
tr:not(:first-child) {css}
```

second solution would be to style all tr's and then override with css for first-child:

```
tr {css}
tr:first-child {override css above}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another option:

```
tr:nth-child(n + 2) {
    /* properties */
}
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, you can put any expression instead of "n + 2". Here "n" number assumes to be a variable  starting from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 to infinity. And if we add up to it  "+ 2", the number within the scope will be 0 + 2 = 2, 1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 2 = 4, 3 + 2 =5, etc... infinity + 2. the the evaluated number stands for the nth element of the element (tr). Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 10):

sounds like the 'first line' you're talking of is your table-header - so you realy should think of using `thead` and `tbody` in your markup ([click here](http://www.idocs.com/tags/tables/_THEAD.html)) which would result in 'better' markup (semantically correct, useful for things like screenreaders) and easier, cross-browser-friendly possibilitys for css-selection (`table thead ... { ... }`)

Answer (score 3):

Though the question has a decent answer already, I just want to stress that the `:first-child` tag goes on the item type that represents the children.

For example, in the code:

```
<div id"someDiv">
     <input id="someInput1" /> 
     <input id="someInput2" />
     <input id="someInput2" />
</div
```

If you want to affect only the second two elements with a margin, but not the first, you would do:

```
#someDiv > input {
     margin-top: 20px;
}
#someDiv > input:first-child{
     margin-top: 0px;
}
```

that is, since the `input`s are the children, you would place `first-child` on the input portion of the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Since `tr:not(:first-child)` is not supported by IE 6, 7, 8. You can use the help of jQuery.
You may find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483996/selecting-table-columns-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I know this is old but why not style all tr elements the way you want all except the first and the use the psuedo class :first-child where you revoke what you specified for all tr elements.

Better descriped by this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DWTr7/1/

```
tr {
    border-top: 1px solid;
}
tr:first-child {
    border-top: none;   
}
```

/Patrik

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a pseudo class selector in your CSS like this:

```
.desc:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

That will not apply the class to the first element with the class .desc.

Here's a JSFiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YYTFT/, and this is a good source to explain pseudo class selectors: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Comment: This will not apply the style to the first element, point. `first-child` ignores classes.

Answer (score -3):

You could create a class and use the class when you define all of your future 's that you want (or don't want) to be selected by the CSS.

This would be done by writing

```
<tr class="unselected">
```

and then in your css having the lines (and using the text-align command as an example) :

```
unselected {
  text-align:center;
}



selected {
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: pleas understand the Question before answering