# Scrapy -Select all table with same class except first one

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get all tables with same class ( **tbl-cenik** ) except first one . I am trying with this answer [select all "tr" except first "tr" in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013701/select-all-tr-elements-except-first-tr-in-a-table-with-css) . But all in vain. here is my sample code

```
response.css('.tbl-cenik:not(:first-child)')
```

I know I can do like this.

```
`response.css('.tbl-cenik:not(:first-child)')[1:]`
```

But that does not look pythonic to me. Any way we can get using selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
.tbl-cenik~.tbl-cenik
```

to fetch all `table` nodes with `@class="tbl-cenik"` that are siblings of the first one (excluding the first itself)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get all tables with `tbl-cenik` class but the first one, then

```
response.css('table.tbl-cenik')[1:]
```

is sufficient and IMHO Pythonic enough. Better, though, would be to use XPath:

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="tbl-cenik" and position() > 1]')
```