# CSS Select all HTML elements except first row of every table

Tags: html, css

When you have a random HTML Page.
I really doesn't matter what the content is or the structure

What I want is to select all elements except the first row (TR) of every table that is exist on the page.

the following selector doesn't work:

```
* :not(tr:first-child){ /* DO SOMETHING */}
```

The table that is rendered is just a plain table whithout any table headers like:

```
<p>123</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>bla bla</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013701/select-all-tr-elements-except-first-tr-in-a-table-with-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hey try my solution and let me know whether it is working or not for u.

Comment: Why the first row? Are your using `td` or `th` in this first row? Can you post your HTML so that we can have a working snippet?

Comment: No there are no table headers just plain old tables:

<table>
  <tr>some tds</tr>
  <tr>some tds</tr>
</table>

It is generated by an wysiwyg tool

Comment: I've added another snippet in my answer, I think it will work for you.

Comment: _This (`:not()`) selector only applies to one element; **you cannot use it to exclude all ancestors**. For instance, body :not(table) a will still apply to links inside of a table, since <tr> will match with the :not() part of the selector._ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to stylize the table content, but not the "header".

An easy way to do that is to use `td`s for the content, and `th`s for the header, as `th` is used to define a header cell in an HTML table. (You can even remember it saying **th** = **t**able **h**eader.)

Then, you'll only have to target the `td`s:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Add your style here */
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p>123</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><!-- Note the ths here! -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td><td>f</td><td>g</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>bla bla</div>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

If you can't use `th`s…
As you may already have some styling applied on your `td`s, it's better to use this kind of selector to match the `td`s that are in the `tr`s except the first one:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

/* Stylize all tds in trs except in the first one! */
table tr:not(:first-child) td {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p>123</p>
<table><!-- All the elements are tds in the trs! -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td><td>f</td><td>g</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>bla bla</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted a specific column, but not including the first row - `tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(column_wanted);` selected what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How about this workaround:

```css
* {
  color: green;
}
table tr:first-of-type td {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>test</p>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. That also come up in my mind but the problem is that The color can not be set in advance. This wil be done by a color picker on the website.